# Помогите разобраться, нужны ли запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу разобраться, нужны ли здесь знаки препинания:

> А я зато посмотри сколько успел сделать.

Нужно ли выделять запятыми "посмотри"?

Answer (score 1):

Обособляй.

(Мало написано, так давайте напишем ещё. Да, буду писать. Я других не читаю.)

[image]

Comment: Источник надо бы указать.

Answer (score 0):

Меняю ответ. Александр своим комментарием донёс до меня мелодию этой фразы.

Да, на мой взгляд, "посмотри" здесь усилительная частица, аналогичная "вот":

> А я зато посмотри сколько успел сделать!

Часть со "сколько" не является придаточным, потому что это "сколько" можно заменить на "столько":

> А я зато сто́лько успел сделать!

Но выразительнее, конечно, исходная фраза или следующая:

> А сколько я всего успел сделать! Ты только посмотри!

Comment: Здесь слово "посмотри" легко заменить словом "вот": А я зато вот сколько успел сделать. И тогда уже не идет речь о привлечении внимания.

Comment: А вы сами-то хотите привлекать внимание? За вас другие писать не могут. Стройте предложения в соответствии с тем смыслом, который донести хотите. "Вот" - это указательно-усилительно-выделительная частица. "Посмотри" - вводное предложение со значением привлечения внимания, выделения тех слов, к которым вводное предложением относится. У "вот" и "посмотри" разные значения. Впрочем, возможно, в чём-то они и схожи. Что хотите - то и используйте.

Comment: "Что хотите - то и используйте". У вас весьма легкомысленное отношение к русскому языку. Я не пишу, а правлю. И тут не знаю как быть.

Comment: Кстати, да! Я уже засомневался в своём ответе. Может, и правда, обособлять ничего не надо...

Comment: "А я зато посмотри сколько успел сделать" - если оставить так, то это хоть и будет русский язык, но это будет не литературный русский язык. Тут либо делаем сложноподчинённое с придаточном ("Посмотри, сколько я зато успел сделать"), либо простое предложение со вставным вводным (А я зато, посмотри, сколько успел сделать.). Вообще, ввводное слово между подлежащим и сказуемым часто кривовато звучит. Можно так сделать: Посмотри, я зато сколько успел сделать.

Comment: А по-моему, очень даже литературный язык это. Сначала просто чересчур формально подошёл и не почувствовал ритма фразы.

Comment: Это не очень литературно, потому что неясна синтаксическая функция слова "посмотри". Сравни: нормативное сложноподчинённое - "Посмотри, сколько я зато успел сделать" и наше  - "А я зато посмотри сколько успел сделать". В чём разница? В том, что тут фактически главное предложение "посмотри" вклинивается в середину придаточного, расчленяя его, что явная ошибка. Можешь, конечно, считать слово "посмотри" частицей "вот" (А я зато вот сколько сделал/ А я зато посмотри сколько сделал), но это ты уже занимаешься морфолого-синтаксическим словообразованием и переводом глагола посмотри в разряд частиц.

Comment: Ну, как с вами спорить? Автор оставила без запятых, но нужно исправить. Например: А я зато, посмотри, Кузьмич, на перловку лещиков одного за другим.

Comment: Во всех спорных случаях автор прав. Всем спасибо, ребята.

Comment: Хех, как можно в таких простых ситуациях искать столь глубинные сложности.

Comment: Ну почему "в простых"? Ситуация двусмысленная.